# Firebase and AngularJS - Insert data into existing child

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a blog in AngularJS and Firebase, and I want to have comments on my posts and store them. For now, I am keeping comments separately, but I would like to store them under the post I am writing them for.

Right now, my Firebase looks like this:

```
"Articles" : {
 "-KIe9mOqMepTsAYipSA6" : {
   "emailId" : "mail@mail.com",
   "post" : "Test",
   "title" : "Test"
 },
 "-KIe9pBW1LnwAgCh96Mp" : {
   "emailId" : "mail@mail.com",
   "post" : "potatoes",
   "title" : "potatos"
 }
}
```

and when I add comment, I want it to look like:

```
"Articles" : {
 "-KIe9mOqMepTsAYipSA6" : {
   "emailId" : "mail@mail.com",
   "post" : "Test",
   "title" : "Test",
   "name" : "Name:,
   "comment" : "Comment"
 },
 "-KIe9pBW1LnwAgCh96Mp" : {
   "emailId" : "mail@mail.com",
   "post" : "potatoes",
   "title" : "potatos",
   "name" : "Name:",
   "comment" : "Comment"
 }
}
```

I tried to wrap $push in $update, and all sorts of things, but nothing really worked.

This is my function for adding comments:

```
$scope.saveComment = function() {
    var name = $scope.article.name;
    var comment = $scope.article.comment;

    var fb = new Firebase("https://blog-2087.firebaseio.com/Articles/");
    var article = $firebase(fb);
    var user = CommonProp.getUser();
    article.$push({ name: name,comment: comment,emailId: user,'.priority': user}).then(function(ref) {
        login.loading = false;
    }, function(error) {
        login.loading = false;
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
    $('#addCommentModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Or I have to save it separately?

Comment: what does `comment` look like? is it a JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

see this closed issue for explanation... https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/402

But you dont need to use `$push` and I couldn't find it in the documentation either.

I tested, and this should work

```
article.push({ name: name, comment: comment, emailId: user,'.priority': user}).then(function(ref) {
    login.loading = false;
}, function(error) {
    login.loading = false;
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Comment: you need to show more code then... it worked for me so I am not sure what you have going one here.